# detecting emails inside an http header

Tags: c#, regex

i am building up a proxy in csharp and one of my tasks is to find emails inside 
an http header, problem is that inside the data that i get i receive %40 instead of 
@, could anyone please tell me how can i detect emails when the @ inside the mail address is being replaced with %40?
here is my code for getting email addresses inside a given string (with @ and not %40 instead)
**Code**:

```
  string regexPattern = @"[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
  Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern);
  MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(this._context.Request.Headers[i]);
  foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(this._context.Request.Headers[i]))
  {// any email address should be printed 
         Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[URL decode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx) your data before running it through the regex:

```
regex.Matches(this._context.Server.UrlDecode(this._context.Request.Headers[i]))
```

Or:

```
regex.Matches(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(this._context.Request.Headers[i]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood your question. Why don't you just replace `@` with `%40` in regex you provided?
So:

```
string regexPattern = @"[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+%40[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OR (|) to allow @ or "%40"

[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+(@|%40)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4}